# PHP multiple matching namespaces in third-party libraries

Tags: php, laravel, cron, namespaces, composer-php

I'm currently writing some Laravel seeders to populate a database in my test environment. I'm using the excellent [*Faker*](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) to generate column values and a Faker plugin called [*CronExpressionGenerator*](https://github.com/swekaj/CronExpressionGenerator) to generate random cron values.

```
$faker->addProvider(new \CronExpressionGenerator\FakerProvider($faker));
$cronTxt = $faker->cron();
```

Then, I'm using a package called [*Cron Expression Parser*](https://github.com/poliander/cron) to generate the timestamp of the next occurrence of each cron expression.

```
$cron = new \Cron\CronExpression($cronTxt, new DateTimeZone(DateTimeZone::UTC));
```

Both of these packages are installed using Composer.

Unfortunately, both packages seem to be using the namespace `\Cron\CronExpression`:

[image]

So when I run my db migration PHP breaks on the function signature.

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Argument 2 passed to Cron\CronExpression::__construct() must be an instance of Cron\FieldFactory, instance of DateTimeZone given
```

**Edit** - looks like the image service isn't working right now. What the screenshot linked above shows is PHPStorm showing two `CronExpression` matches, one for each:

- `vendor/dragonmantank/cron-expression/src/Cron`
- `vendor/polander/cron/src/Cron`

Comment: I don't think there's a way around this beyond forking the second library and modifying the namespace and using your VCS repository, or just copying it to your project and modifying it there.   It does just seem to be one class after all.   Such a simple namespace of `Cron` is a pretty bad design.

Comment: Is there any practical reason why you're using `poliander/cron` instead of many other packages which provides similar functionality and does not conflict with much more popular packages?